# Cannot reverse url in template Django

Tags: django, templates, url, django-rest-framework, reverse

I got stuck with reverse url name in `custom-text-form.html` file.

This is my `custom-text-form.html`.

```
{% load rest_framework %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'tool:custom-text' %}" method="POST" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/horizontal' %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

configs/urls.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^run/media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
    path('api/', include('apps.tool.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

tool/urls.py.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from .views import CustomTextViewSet, UploadImageViewSet, FormCustomTextView

app_name = 'tool'

router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('upload-image', UploadImageViewSet)
router.register('custom-text', CustomTextViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls), name='custom-text'),
    url('form-custom-text', FormCustomTextView.as_view())
]
```

I got this error `NoReverseMatch at /api/form-custom-text` 
when trying request url `http://localhost:8000/api/form-custom-text`
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyjHw.png)

My `TEMPLATES` config

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My folders structure:
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyjHw.png)
[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIeGs.png)

I was trying to add `namespace='tool'` in `tool/url.py` but still not working.

Any one could help!!
Thanks

Comment: You can not refer to an `include`, since that is a *set* of urls, you need to specify a single one, so give the target view a name.

Comment: thanks.
It worked when I add this line `path('api/', include(('apps.tool.urls', 'tool'), namespace='tool'))` to configs/urls

Comment: can you explain more!!

Comment: t worked when I access this url http://localhost:8000/api/custom-text. But in url http://localhost:8000/api/custom-text occurred error 
` NoReverseMatch at /api/form-custom-text Reverse for 'custom-text' not found`. `'custom-text' is not a valid view function or pattern name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `configs/urls.py`

```
....

urlpatterns = [
    ....,
    path('api/', include(('apps.tool.urls', 'tool'), namespace='tool'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Since Django > 2.0 using `Path` you need to specify `app_name` and `namespace`

Suggestion: Try to use `django-extension`. There are many useful commands already registered. You can use `python manage.py show_urls` to show complete urls schema include `namespace` and `name` of url

Comment: it worked when I access this url `http://localhost:8000/api/custom-text`.
But in url `http://localhost:8000/api/custom-text` occurred error 
```
NoReverseMatch at /api/form-custom-text
Reverse for 'custom-text' not found. 'custom-text' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
````

Comment: I suggest you to include `django-extension` in your project. There are many useful commands already registered. For detail, check https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

After installed, then run command `python manage.py show_urls` to show your full urls schema contains `namespace` and `name` of url

Comment: I had included `django-extension` and find the exactly path.
Thank you.